# Gradle cannot build Webpack for Spring

Tags: spring, reactjs, gradle, npm, webpack

I'm trying to integrate `ReactJS` into a `Spring` project for the first time, and I'm following [this tutorial](https://objectpartners.com/2016/04/22/using-webpack-with-gradle/) to do so with `Gradle`. I am receiving this error message

> basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\,/,g')")
>         ^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list at createScript (vm.js:80:10) at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:599:28) at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:646:10) at Module.load (module.js:554:32) at tryModuleLoad
>   (module.js:497:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3) at
>   Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10) at startup
>   (bootstrap_node.js:187:16) at bootstrap_node.js:608:3 :webpack FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':webpack'.
>
> > Process 'command 'C:\Users\KyleLaptop\programming\java\SDV-ModSight.gradle\nodejs\node-v8.9.3-win-x64\node.exe''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 1

There is a similar question with `python` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743880/webpack-unable-to-bundle-due-to-syntaxerror), but making that change seems to have no effect. I tried hard coding in the `webpack.cmd` but it had a similar effect with this error

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @IF
>   EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" ( ^SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

It might still be that `react` is not reading my OS, or I also read that the problem could be that the program is running shell scripts as `javascript`. Here are my

**Build.Gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-
plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0"
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.moowork.node'

group = 'org.SDVModSight'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

node {
    version = '8.9.3'
    npmVersion = '5.5.1'
    download = true
    //distBaseUrl = Custom install location
}

war {
    baseName = 'webpack-gradle'
    version = '0.0.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    vaadinVersion = '8.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('org.webjars:npm:3.9.3')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}

import com.moowork.gradle.node.task.NodeTask

task webpack(type: NodeTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
    script = project.file('node_modules/.bin/webpack')
}

processResources.dependsOn 'webpack'

clean.delete << file('node_modules')
clean.delete << file('src/main/resources/static/built')
```

and my **package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "sdvmodsight",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "website to handle xnb conflicts",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@github.com/KyMann/SDV-Modsight.git"
  },
  "author": "Kyle T. Mann",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/KyMann/SDV-Modsight/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/KyMann/SDV-Modsight",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "rest": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "less": "^2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "keywords": []
}
```

Been stuck on this for a while. Any help is appreciated.