# Kotlin JS Client and JVM Server build webpack SyntaxError

Tags: windows, gradle, kotlin, npm, webpack

I'm trying to build JS Client and JVM server kotlin project generated by IntelliJ IDEA. 
Getting error:

```
[...]\node_modules\.bin\webpack:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Found that it's common problem with npm and webpack on Windows and could be fixed by editing package.json file.
[Webpack unable to bundle due to SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743880/webpack-unable-to-bundle-due-to-syntaxerror)
Problem that package.json is generated by build itself and I don't know how to apply this fix in my situation.

Looks that it should be applied somewhere around this code in build.gradle:

```
jvmJar {
    dependsOn(jsBrowserWebpack)
    from(new File(jsBrowserWebpack.entry.name, jsBrowserWebpack.outputPath))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed in recent kotlin plugin version for idea - 1.3.50